# Handsontable : prepopulate columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I want to do a something similar to http://handsontable.com/demo/prepopulate.html excepted that I want to pre-populate columns and not rows.

I undertstand that I have to use a function to define the default rendering. However, it only seems to work when adding rows but not colums : news rows are filled with "default" but not the columns.

This is what I tried :

```
function defaultValueRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  var args = $.extend(true, [], arguments);
  if (args[5] === null) {
      td.style.color = 'red';
      args[5] = "default";      
  }
  Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, args);
}

var myData = [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];

$("#exampleGrid").handsontable({
    data: myData,
    minSpareCols: 1,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
            var cellProperties = {};
            cellProperties.type = {renderer: defaultValueRenderer}
            return cellProperties;
        }
});​
```

The defaultValueRenderer function seems not to be called when adding the spare columns (only for spare rows).

http://jsfiddle.net/QtGau/2/

Thank your for your hints

*EDIT* : the value seems to be an empty string. I might use this as a workarround, however I believe I'm misunderstanding something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got no reply, I'm answering my self. I hack arround using === null or === "".
It works, it's ugly, still better than nothing ;)